# How to send data to "views.py" in django with some data

Tags: javascript, python, django

Here is My html from where i am sending data

```
<div class="advanced-search">
                        <!-- <button type="button" class="category-btn">All Categories</button> -->
                        <select class='category-btn col-12' id='Catagory_search'>
                            <option value="Shop">IN SHOP</option>
                            <option value="Blog">IN BLOG</option>
                            <option value="Faq">IN FAQ</option>
                        </select>
                        <form action="" class="input-group" style="float: right;" id='AdvancseSearch'>
                            <input type="text" name='search' placeholder="What do you need?">
                            <button type="submit"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Here the Ajax With which i am sending GET request with data (search)

```
 $('#AdvancseSearch').on('submit', function(e) {
        ctg = document.getElementById('Catagory_search').value

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            url: "/Search/serach/" + ctg,
            data: {
                'search': $('input[name=search]').val()
            },
            encode: true,
        })
    })
```

The views.py function which will redirect

```
def Search(request,ctg):
search = request.GET.get('search')
if ctg == "Shop":
    d = Item.objects.filter(item_titile__icontains=search)
    send_dict = {'items':d}
    return render(request,'home/product.html',send_dict)
```

The problem is that that when i send data to my views.py it succesfully send data **"search"**
but it will not **RENDER** me to my desire (home/product.html) page it stay on current page

Comment: You aren't preventing the default form submit process. The page is being reloaded when the form itself submits. Also a redirect in ajax request will not redirect the current page, it will only redirect the ajax response

Comment: It is not really clear what the process flow you are expecting is.

Comment: ok but what if i want to send the drop down value in <form> is it possible

Comment: I want to send search value which is in drop down above the form but when i send GET request to link Than is there anyway to send the dropdown value too?

Comment: Why not put the `<select>` in the form and just submit the whole form?

Comment: it will disturb my html code, basically i am using templates

Comment: Well you could just change the `action` of the form using the value of the select instead of using ajax if you are expecting a whole new redirect to load in the browser

Comment: i need url in action like "/Search/serach/ ?{the value of the select }?" if posible pls guid.thank u

Comment: In your submit handler can do `$(this).attr('action', "/Search/serach/" + ctg)`

Comment: Hurrrey! its work thankx Charlie